# VBS doesn't open Outlook

Tags: vbscript

I try to run a vbs to open Outlook after i scanned a doc, it scans the document on Windows 10, but doesn't open Outlook, have you guys any idea?

BR Alex

```
Create the Outlook session.          
      Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

          ' Create the message.
          Set objOutlookMsg  = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

          Set objOutlookAttach = objOutlookMsg.Attachments.Add(output)
          
          objOutlookMsg.Display
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason was a missing permission on the folder where the scanned file was stored